# How to limit the number of characters in a cell <td> using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to figure out how I can limit the number of characters in a cell of a table using jQuery. I have found ways to limit the characters in text boxes but that isn't working. Thank you in advance. The code shown below what makes a new row for my table and what i have attempted to do in order to limit it to 30 characters as well as what it currently looks like.

JQuery

```
let category = $("#categoryNameInsert");
let weight = $("#weightInsert");
$("#categoryInsertButton").click(function(){
    let markup2 = "<tr><td contenteditable=\"true\" class=\"categoryName\"></td><td contenteditable=\"true\" class=\"gradeName\"></td><td>Click to edit</td></tr>";
    $("#addCategoryTable").append(markup2);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('categoryName').each(function() {
        let td = $(this);
        td.text(td.text().substring(0, 50));
        });
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="addCategory"
  <h5 id="addCategoryHeader">Add a grade category</h5>
  <table id="addCategoryTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Weight(%)</th>
    <th><button id="categoryInsertButton">Add Category</button></th>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What it looks like when you press add category a new empty row pops up and in that row you can edit the cells and that's what I'm trying to limit the characters of.
[Image of problem table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUZig.png)
[Another image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKXHa.png)

Comment: Why not use an if statement to validate the entry (.length) and change your placeholder text to something like "Click to edit (Max. 30 Chars.)"?

Comment: so i would say if and then the length is 30 then what

Answer (score 0):

It's not `$('categoryName')`, but `$('.categoryName')`. Notice the dot before the name. That notifies that this is a `class`. Your `.each()` was not applicable to anything because you have used the wrong selector.

Comment: @BerkOtt what do you experience?

Comment: @BerkOtt instead of .substring(0, 50) you might want .substring(0, 30) to limit to 30 characters.

Comment: Its like it was before and the substring makes no difference

Comment: The table is in a popup

Comment: and i need to limit the characters because i dont want a user to be able to make it go off the chart and also to not mess up the other charts or places that information will be used

Comment: @BerkOtt can you edit your question and add your HTML? Also, do you want to prevent certain length as they type?

Comment: yes, I want to limit the length while a user types in the table cell. so once they typed 30 characters,  the text will not get long in the cell anymore.

Comment: @BerkOtt then you might want to change td.text(td.text().substring(0, 50)); to td.text(td.text().substring(0, 30));